# Google maps exclude locations out of a specific range

Tags: google-maps, algolia

I have a search index of offices that have multiple locations. I would like to filter these offices by an address and display them on a map. When searching for a specific address, some offices have locations in the desired location and also irrelevant locations. For example, if I search New York, the index returns two companies

```
company_a.locations = [New York, San Francisco]
company_b.locations = [New York]
```

The problem is that I will now display pins for all 3 locations, including San Francisco even though all I really care about is New York. This is true if I searched for a specific zipcode in New York and I received some locations that are actually in NJ, so it's highly specific to the query.

What logic can I implement to understand that an arbitrary location is not relevant to the search results?

I am doing my best to define the problem and realize it's difficult to define so I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction. If helpful, I am using [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) and google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could imagine setting up your records a bit differently, in order to have more information about each location:

`{
    "name": "company_a",
    "_geoloc": [
        {
          "city": "NY",
          "lat": 40.7128,
          "lng": 74.0059
        },
        {
          "city": "SF",
          "lat": 37.7749,
          "lng": 122.4194
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "company_b",
     "_geoloc": [
        {
          "city": "NY",
          "lat": 40.7128,
          "lng": 74.0059
        }
    ]
}`

The `_geoloc` field is a filed used by Algolia's [geosearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/geo-search/) feature (that could be useful in your use case).

If you use the builtin geosearch, you won't have to filter the records in your front end to remove alternatives. If you use regular filters, you will have to check the results of Algolia and removing the alternatives that are located in different city.

For the sake of completeness, you could also simply duplicate your record, in order to have a single location per record:

`{
    "name": "company_a",
    "location": "SF"
},
{
    "name": "company_a",
    "location": "NY"
}`

Comment: I went with the single location per record and think it's the most maintainable. Thanks for the suggestion.